# Non Blocking Socket

Tags: c

A non blocking socket is the one where we call fcntl() method and associate the O_NONBLOCK flag with it. Can any one tell me what else is required to convert a normal TCP_IP socket into a non blocking socket?

What problems may arise if non-blocking sockets are made to work very well with Windows servers?

Comment: Sounds too much like homework. Second question, can't come up with a feasible project that would require two widely disparate pieces of elementary OS programming.

Comment: Actually it is intended to be used for not waiting the incoming traffic in online environment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Example init for linux may look like this:

```
int flags;
s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) // ret 5
setsockopt(s, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) 
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, [1], 4) 
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) 
flags = fcntl(s,F_GETFL,0);
assert(flags != -1);
fcntl(s, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
connect(s, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(5001), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.68")}, 16)
```

Basic white paper from sun:

[sun asych net](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1602/sockets-22932.html#sockets-40)

On windows You use Overlapped IO sockets to get non blocking networking.

[Look here and in MSDN how to write code with OVERLAPPED structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapped_I/O)

On Linux use epoll().

On solaris socket().

Be aware to read or write to a socket when it's not ready.
(select-output) Because You may receive EAGAIN error.

Great cross platform library (but C++ and new c++ standard candidate) is boost::asio.

It uses native system asynchronous methods.

[boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this in C. What needs to be taken care off is used on windows or linux servers?