# How are ioctl() and/or fcntl() used for writing a non-blocking socket?

Tags: sockets, nonblocking, ioctl, fcntl

I am trying to learn how to write a non-blocking socket. Can anyone please explain that what roles do ioctl() and fcntl() play in this (i.e. what are the roles of file descriptors in creating a non-blocking socket. A code snippet as an example with explanation will be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NON BLOCKING Socket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525050/non-blocking-socket)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use one or the other to set `O_NONBLOCK`. Surely you already discovered that?

Comment: Thanks for replying, but yeah, I did. What I exactly want to know is the mechanism as to how it works. :)

Comment: Meaning what exactly? The mechanism of either is that it puts the socket into non-blocking mode.

Comment: Yeah, ignore that. I got it. Thanks.